# Prompt not showing for select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code which should be showing a select tag with a list of items and default 'Select subject' but it's not showing the prompt item:

```
<%= select_tag 'subject', options_for_select(['Hello', 'Billing', 'Other'], {:prompt => 'Select subject'}) %>
```

Any ideas why?

I've managed to get it working using: `<%= select_tag 'subject', options_for_select({'Select subject'=>'','Hello'=>'Hello','Billing'=>'Billing','Other'=>'Other'}) %>` but feels more long winded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
<%= select_tag 'subject', options_for_select(['Hello', 'Billing', 'Other'], ),:prompt => 'Select subject' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

<%= select_tag 'subject', options_for_select(['Hello', 'Billing', 'Other']), {:prompt => 'Select subject'} %>
try to over the bracket before the prompt.